# Get the command line for the process that owns a window

Tags: shell, command-line, lubuntu

How can I detect in Lubuntu the command line invocation of a process from one of its windows, so that I can run it later from the command line?

Comment: I'm not sure what you asking about but you might be asking about `xprop`.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: On Raspbian I can open the "GUI Network Dialog" by clicking the right mouse on the Network Widget on the Taskbar. In need to know how to open that network dialog from commandline.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Are you trying to run Windows programs from your command line while being booted into Lubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine a couple of commands:

```
$ cat /proc/$(xprop | grep PID | awk '{print $3}')/cmdline | tr '\0' ' ';echo
```

`xprop` will wait until you click on a window. When you do, it prints the process id number and other info (`grep` and `awk` clean that up) and `cat` shows the file `/proc/cmd/PID/cmdline` which holds the command line, with arguments, but uses zero as separator. Then with `tr` you the zero caracters into spaces. A final echo leaves the output in its own line.

This is not meant to be performant but, hopefully, readable.

You can also call `ps` with the flags you need, in order to get information on the process:

```
$ ps FLAGS -p $(xprop | grep PID | awk '{print $3}')
```

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I will try to use this Information.